# Serialization concept in java, got stuck in concept

Tags: java, serialization

i am not getting the exact concept of serialization, help me out and also please help me to understand this concept of `d.getCollar().getCollarSize()`, how this is working? And can we call directly getColarSize(); method after creating the object of that class directly?

Like,

```
Collar ab=new Collar(); 
ab.getCollarSize();
```

And Code is given below:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializeDog {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Collar c=new Collar(2);
        Dog d=new Dog(c, 5);
        System.out.println("before collar size is :"+d.getCollar().getCollarSize());

        try{
            FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("serializeDog.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(d);
            os.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


        try{
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("serializeDog.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            d=(Dog)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("after collar size is: "+d.getCollar().getCollarSize());
    }
}





class Dog implements Serializable{
    private Collar theCollar;
    private int dogSize;
    public Dog(Collar collar,int size)
        {
        theCollar=collar;
        dogSize=size;
        }
    public Collar getCollar()
        {
        return theCollar;
        }
}





class Collar implements Serializable
{
    private int collarSize;
    public Collar(int size)
    {
        collarSize=size;
    }
    public int getCollarSize()
    {
        return collarSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this about serialization or basic java?

Comment: its both, Serialization and basic of java @John3136

Comment: It seems like confusion is not about serializtion

Comment: @Charlie, yes dear, i got the concept but got stuck in above concept, need help.

Comment: its all about object , you are serializing and de-serializing Dog object .
Once you get Dog object ,you get everything in this object , The only way to get Collor object from Dog object is getCollar() ,so yes you can not call it directly unless you serialize Collar Object

Comment: I think you you should read some document about java  serailzation and de-serialization. There is no crucial points in your question.
Read: http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/core-java-tutorial/java-serialization-concept-example/ and http://www.javabeginner.com/uncategorized/java-serialization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look on following code

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializeDog {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Collar c=new Collar(2);
        Dog d=new Dog(c, 5);
        System.out.println("before collar size is :"+d.getCollar().getCollarSize());

        try{
            FileOutputStream fs=new FileOutputStream("serializeDog.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream os=new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(d);
            os.close();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}


        try{
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("serializeDog.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            d=(Dog)ois.readObject();
            ois.close();

        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        System.out.println("after collar size is: "+d.getCollar().getCollarSize());
    }
}





class Dog implements Serializable{
    private Collar theCollar;
    private int dogSize;
    public Dog(Collar collar,int size)
        {
        theCollar=collar;
        dogSize=size;
        }
    public Collar getCollar()
        {
        return theCollar;
        }
}
```